# Extract a specific formatted output from a nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

Using a csv extract from a registration system I am attempting to format the data to use as contact/distribution list import into a virtual meeting application. Using the following function I am able to pull the needed data into a nested list `([name1, email1] [name2, email2],...)`.

```
def createDistributionList():
with open(fileOpen) as readFile, open('test2.txt', 'w') as writeFile:
    data = pd.read_csv(readFile)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Attendee Name', 'Attendee Email'])
    distList = df.values.tolist()
    print(' '.join(map(str, distList)))
```

The format I need the data in is one long string - `name1(email1);name2(email2);...`

I have been unable to get the output that I am looking for. Any assistance or a pointer to a relevant reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for that:

```
tup = (["name1", "email1"], ["name2", "email2"], ["name3", "email3"])

print(";".join(["{}({})".format(l[0], l[1]) for l in tup]))
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Could you please accept the answer and upvote if it was helpful? HappyCoding!